# JSF + primefaces calling getter way too much times

Tags: java, performance, jsf, primefaces

I read all answers on this topic (not only) on SO, but none of this solves my problem.
I have datatable:

```
<p:dataTable 
                value="#{reportBean.reportData.rows}"
                var="row" 
                styleClass="listBlock dataTableOverflowAuto fullScreenTable"
                rendered="#{!reportBean.reportData.grouped}">
                 <f:facet name="header">
                    #{msg['report.table.header']}
                </f:facet>

                <p:column>
                    #{row.integrationName}
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    #{row.integrationId}
                </p:column>

                <p:column>
                    #{row.service}
                </p:column>

                <p:columns value="#{reportBean.reportData.columns}"
                           var="column">  
                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        #{column}
                    </f:facet>  
                    <h:outputText value="#{row.getData(column)}" escape="false" />  
                </p:columns>
```

getReportData() on reportBean is very simple (no calculation):

```
public ReportDataInterface getReportData() {
        return reportData;
}
```

And the data returned are:

```
public class NoneGroupedReportData implements ReportDataInterface {
    private int counter = 0;
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private List<String> columns = new LinkedList<String>();
    public void addRow(Row row) {
        addColumns(row);
    }

    public List<String> getColumns() {
        counter++;
        logger.debug("getColumns called {} times", counter);
        return columns;
    }

....
```

And the result is

> 2013-05-15 07:38:07,405 () DEBUG NoneGroupedReportData - getColumns
>   called 21600 times

For dataTable with ~30 rows and 10 columns.

I know why JSF calls getters many times, but almost 22k, why? When i need more results (>1000) it will not render in 5 minutes, because it endlessly calls this getter.
Where is the problem and how can i achieve the state in which getColumns() is called for each row max 5~10 times?

I have tried using jstl c:set "caching" but without any result (http://qussay.com/2013/04/19/caching-and-reusing-an-evaluated-el-expression-in-jsf/)

EDIT: My guess is that getter calling is not "wrong" but sign that i am using dataTable in the wrong way.

Comment: You're not giving the full story here. Where does the instance of `NoneGroupedReportData` sit?

Comment: It is view scoped. And instance of NoneGroupedReportData is a property of the managed bean.

Comment: You refer reportData at least 3 times and they may be unnecessary. it not necessary that fetch rows and columns separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are accessing two times the same data structure,

```
N: <p:dataTable value="#{reportBean.reportData.rows}" ...
```

and then **INSIDE** the same p:dataTable you are using

```
M: <p:columns value="#{reportBean.reportData.columns}" ...
```

That causes a **N * M** product that a the end gives your 21600 times, because you are accessing the **same** data structure in **two nested tags**...

It is not clear what kind of datatable are you trying to construct, but I think you should *reorganize* your data structure.

The simpler solution, **in case you are trying to put multiple values inside one single column for each row** will be changing M to:

```
M: <p:columns value="#{rows.columns}" ...
```

But that will involve changing your data structure to put your **columns** component into your **rows** component.

Regards,